# Long chatroom name overflows sidebar widget

Tags: bug, design, chat, sidebar

On some places, most notably the per-site Meta homepages and the moderator flag dashboard, a chat sidebar widget is shown, which shows how many people are chatting on the server and two recently active rooms. However, if the name of the room is too long, it overflows:

[image]