# Meta post title overflows sidebar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, title, community-bulletin

On [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/), the sidebar has a Hot Meta Post whose title contains a URL, and this URL overflows outside the edge of the sidebar.

> [image: image of sidebar]

The displayed title of the question is `Why is this question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/40266/20829 marked...` where the URL starts on a new line and extends beyond the edge of the sidebar.

I expect the same issue will come up whenever a very long word appears in a title.

It is known that the same error occurs in the chatroom sidebar if the name of a chatroom is very long: [Long chatroom name overflows sidebar widget](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345792/313042)

Comment: Other case of overflowing things: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/340471#340471

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for catching this! This has now been fixed so that all sidebar URLs will wrap as expected. The fix for this will go out in the next build of the site.

Comment: Is this a change in stacks that will also fix other overflow problems, like the one I linked in my comment under the question?

Comment: Thanks for your link to the other overflowing bug! The scope of the change I made was only to fix the sidebar and not a greater change to how text is handled in Stacks. I did fix a similar bug last week, but I'm not yet certain if it fixes the problem you outlined in your link, I'll have to take a look. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350726/text-in-bounty-box-pokes-out-of-the-box-on-mobile/359541#359541

Comment: I just had a look, and although that post is now deleted the issue still pertains (using the responsive site design on mobile at least).