# Text in bounty box pokes out of the box on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

When viewing a question with a bounty on mobile, the text in the blue post notice box overflows out onto the white next to it instead of sticking neatly in the box.

[image: screenshot of a bounty; the word "bounty" is overflowing out of the box]

Both the word "bounty" and the end of the link in the bounty text are sticking out of the post notice.

Comment: We should really start collecting all those “long link overflows container” reports and fix them in one go.

Comment: Thanks for raising this. We're actively looking at how to mobile views are rendering and when we have more updates on this, will post here.

Comment: Just noticed the same behavior in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64847061/5675325) (Stack Overflow), as [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI3Z5.jpg).

Answer (score 12):

This has been fixed and should be fixed on all sites. The text will now wrap correctly. Thanks for reporting this!

(As a side note, this is my very first bugfix as a Stack Overflow employee! )

Comment: Congrats on your first bugfix, that many may follow!